# Windows fatal exception: stack overflow when trying to print beautiful soup content

Tags: python, windows, exception, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print the beautifulsoup content from this link: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/0001047469-11-006302.txt
using the code

```py
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'xxx'})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

After running the code, spyder throw out the follow error and automatically restart the kernel
I have searched almost everywhere but found no post describing this exact issue. Anyone has any thought?

```
Windows fatal exception: stack overflow


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00002434 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\formatter.py", line 123 in attributes
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1640 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1777 in decode_contents
  File "C:\Users\Arnold\anaconda3\envs\Exp\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1683 in decode
  ...


Restarting kernel...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS4 is also using recursion to find all elements and Python has a recursion limit (check with [sys.getrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)).

The error you're facing might be due to the HTML doc has too many child elements.

You may want to use [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) to increase the limit. For example:

```py
import requests
import bs4
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'xxx'})
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Please note, if you set the limit too high, it may cause an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.

Comment: Thank you Thy, I tried your suggestion however it did not resolve the issue. I think I was not clear in the post, I want to emphasis that I had no problem generating the soup object (this line—soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(session.get(link).content, 'html.parser'—runs perfectly). The error only occurs when I try to print the soup/or save it to a txt file. Also I am using python 3.8.8 (spyder 5.2.2), and windows 10.

Comment: When I tried the script, I could print/save to a file. I could get the element too, for example `soup.a` gives me `<a href="#bg77301a_main_toc">Table of Contents</a>`. Maybe try increasing the recursion limit more.

Comment: Hi Thy, that's interesting, would you mind sharing the version of your python, spyder as well as bs4 (so I can try to either update or downgrade). Thanks again, I might not be able to reply you today cause it's late now. Thank you for  your time and response.

Comment: (i tried with a limit of 100000 still no luck, same error)

Comment: I didn't use Spyder but PyCharm. If you don't need to `print(soup)` or save it, can you use `.find()` or `.find_all()` (e.g. soup.a, soup.p, etc)? I think the recursion is happening in `.__str__()` when you print(soup) and iPython is unable to handle it. Actually, your `soup` contains the elements from the link, that's the reason why the error occurs only when you try to print the soup. Increasing recursion limit works in PyCharm, it might be due to it's using CPython instead of iPython kernel (CMIIW).

Comment: Btw, I could replicate your issue when I'm using Spyder though.

Comment: Also, if you can use `.find()` or `find_all()`, you don't even need to increase recursion limit.

Comment: Hi Thy, yes I can use .find() and .find_all() for many items, but the error occurs when I run soup.find_all('document'). I can print out the first document by print(soup.find('document')), but when I run soup.find_all('document'), the same error occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try Pycharm and let you know if it works on my side.

Comment: It may took a while because I am new to pycharm

Comment: I installed pycharm and reran the code, first I got the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". Once I adjust the limit by "sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)", another issue occurred:" Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
, do you have any idea why

Comment: Hi Thy I still have not figured out exactly why it give me the exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) when I try to save the soup as a string in txt file, this error also occurs when I set my recursion limit to a super high number (e.g. 1000,000), so i think it has to be related to this recursion limit thing. The good thing is that it doesn't restart my kernel anymore because I can handle it as an exception error and move on with the rest of the code. This helps me greatly because I have millions of other links to process (I will miss a couple problematic links but get the rest saved).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I will check your answer.  If I ever figure out why the exit code "exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)" when I try to save the soup I will also add it here.